# How to run asp.net web api with docker container without https?

Tags: asp.net, docker, http, containers, webapi

> I am trying to run an asp.net web api with docker container but I get status code 400 (Bad request) as the response when I send a request to the api. The api works fine when I run it via visual studio. I mean that I can send a request to the api and get back desired response.

> this is the StartUp.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebApi_Token v1"));
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // this is commented out just to create container

            app.UseCors(c => c.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());


            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

> here is the launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65362/",
      "sslPort": 44304
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApi_Token": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      //"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44305;http://localhost:44304"
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44304"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": false
    },
    "WSL": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      //"launchUrl": "https://localhost:4001",
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:4001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:4001;http://localhost:4000"
      },
      "distributionName": ""
    }
  }
}
```

> And here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myApi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./myApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "myApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApi.dll"]
```

> I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I now nothing about dotnet and wanted to build your API but you didnt send all the required files so what i can propose is just replacing all "localhost" occurences by "0.0.0.0", this should work.

Keep me informed please, and if this doesnt work just paste a single API (like a hello world) to test, and how to build it etc. I will do all the testing here.

bguess.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to add `"urls=http://0.0.0.0:80"` to the entrypoint of my Dockerfile.
In your case, it would be something like

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApi.dll", "urls=http://0.0.0.0:80"]
```